# Auto-suggest search box using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried a downloaded code for auto-suggest search box but it didn't work. It does not display anything from my database. I'm still new in this programming language especially in using AJAX and JavaScript.

Here's my code:

dbcon2.php

```
<?php 

$con2['host'] = 'localhost';
$con2['user'] = 'root';
$con2['pass'] = 'thirteen';
$con2['db'] = 'pis';
$sel2 = mysql_connect($con2['host'], $con2['user'], $con2['pass']);
mysql_select_db($con2['db'], $sel2);
mysql_set_charset("utf-8");

$datab2 = $con2['db'];?>
```

set_creditlimit.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Autocomplete search using php, mysql and ajax</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".search").keyup(function()
        {
            var searchid = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
            if (searchid!='') 
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "search.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html)
                        {
                            $("#result").html(html).show();
                        }
                    });
                }return false;
        });

        jQuery("#result").live("click", function(e){
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
            var decoded = $("</div>").html($name).text();
            $('#searchid').val(decoded);
        });

        jQuery(document).live("click", function(e){
            var $clicked = $(e.target);
            if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")) {
                jQuery("#result").fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $('#searchid').click(function(){
            jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page-inner">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>ACL</h2>
            </div> <!-- <div class="col-md-12"> -->
        </div> <!-- <div class="row"> -->

        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Start of Form -->
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                         Set-up Allowable Credit Limit
                    </div> <!-- <div class="panel-heading"> -->
                    <!-- End of Heading -->
                    <!-- Start of Body -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <label>Search Employee:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="searchid" placeholder="Search Employee" class="search">
                                </div>
                                <div id="result"></div>
                            </div>
                            <br />

                            <!-- ------------- -->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <label>Position:</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />

                            <!-- ------------- -->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <label>Department:</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />

                            <!-- ------------- -->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <label>Business Unit:</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />

                            <!-- ------------- -->

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                    <label>Allowed Credit Limit:</label>
                                    <input class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />

                            <!-- ------------- -->

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <center>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right fa-1x">&nbsp;Submit</i></button>
                                    </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div> <!-- <div class="panel-body"> -->
                </div> <!-- <div class="panel panel-success"> -->
            </div> <!-- <div class="col-md-12"> -->
        </div> <!-- <div class="row"> -->

    </div> <!-- <div id="page-inner"> -->
</div> <!-- <div id="page-wrapper"> -->
</body>
</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php

include('dbcon2.php');
if ($_POST) 
{
$q = $_POST['search'];
$sql_res = mysql_query("SELECT emp_id, name from employee3 where emp_id like '%$q%' or name like '%$q%' order by emp_id LIMIT 5 ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)) 
{
$emp_id = $row['emp_id'];
$name = $row['name'];
$b_emp_id = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$b_name = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
$fina_emp_id = str_ireplace($q, $b_emp_id, $emp_id);
$final_name = str_ireplace($q, $b_name, $name);
?>
<div class="show" align="left">
    <span class="name"><?php echo $fina_emp_id; ?></span>
</div>
<?php
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: Nobody should search their database as presented here. Please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong data format in the ajax call.

It should be like this:

```
data: { search: searchid }
```

try this and it should work i believe.

Refer this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: it doesn't work sir...is there something wrong with my database connection?

Comment: yes may be, use `mysql_error()` to check..and you should start using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` immediately.